# natural=beach without all the wrong tagged sand areas golf bunker or sandy places in zoos

Tags: openstreetmap, query

I would like to get natural=beach (places along a body of water at best places where you can have a bath). Unfortunately the query natural=beach ends up often with wrong "single" tagged sand areas like golf bunker e.g.: https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/sC3 or sandy places in zoos or forests. Single tagged I mean there's not any other helpful tag I could use to exclude.

Does anyone have an idea to query natural=beach without all the wrong "single" tagged sand areas like golf bunkers or sandy places in zoos or forests.

Comment: Which platform are you using? Is OSM API? Can you share to us some code? Please, [edit](https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/257070/edit) your question and add more details.

Comment: @aldo_tapia yes, I'm using the OSM API but I form the query with overpass-turbo.eu: http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/s64

Comment: "natural=beach" when it isn't a beach is a mistagging.  Is it worth perhaps talking to the people behind [Maproulette](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/MapRoulette) and creating a challenge around that?  It won't help you in the short term but longer term it will fix the data,

Comment: after a while of research I'm close to an solution: https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/sC2  finds all beaches close by an golf_course (who are wrong tagged), but I need the opposite. The around filter means which are at most any meters away from anything. I would like to exclude them. I need an expression to find  anything which are at least any meters away from an other thing.